# get selected dropdown value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can I get the value of selected drop down (1,2 or 3)? my js as below

```
$scope.priority = [
    {
     "level":"Urgent",
     "index":1
    },

    {
     "level":"Very Important",
     "index":2
    },

    {
     "level":"Important",
     "index":3
    }
];
```

html

```
<select class="btn btn-priority" ng-options="p.level for p in priority">
   <option value="">priority</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="selectedPriority" class="btn btn-priority" ng-options="p.level for p in priority">
   <option value="">priority</option>
</select>
```

You can use ng-model attribute to get it.

```
$scope.selectedPriority
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayanthakgjls/79pDQ/45/)

Comment: I got an object. I tried ng-model="selectedPriority.index" to try to get the index but it returned undefined?

Comment: See I have added the jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `ng-model` you should use the `select as label for value in array` syntax to specify the value of options:

```
<select ng-model="selectedPriority" ng-options="p.index as p.level for p in 
 priority">
   <option value="">priority</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/4799/)**</kbd>

This allows you to get rid of `ng-change` overhead. Read more in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).